# is it possible to connect two Sonarqube servers?

Tags: sonarqube

is it possible to connect two Sonarqube servers in such a way that some subset of Server 1's projects appear under Server 2's projects?

Answer (score 3):

No. If you really want this, you'll need to analyze the projects once for each server.